# PHP - Filtering e-mail adresses

Tags: php, validation, email

I have a registration script and I want that only users with a specific e-mail are able to register. (for example: all e-mails must end with "@test-test.com")

This is my code:

```html
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid e-mail Adress!</p>';
    }
```

I know that I cannot use FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL for that... can anybody show me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try my updated code, which will allow you set of allowed email address

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first make sure that the email is valid using `filter_var`, and then see if it has the correct domain, e.g. via a `preg_match`:

```
function tellMeIfThisIsValid($email) {
    $allowedDomain = '@test-test.com';

    $isValid = FALSE;
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
        if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($allowedDomain) . '$/', $email)) {
            $isValid = TRUE;
        }
    }
    printf("%-25s => %s" . PHP_EOL, $email, $isValid ? 'valid' : 'not valid');
}

tellMeIfThisIsValid('test@test-test.com');
tellMeIfThisIsValid('test.test@test-test.com');
tellMeIfThisIsValid('@test-test.com');
tellMeIfThisIsValid('test@test-test.com.se');
tellMeIfThisIsValid('test@anothertest-test.com');
tellMeIfThisIsValid('test@testtest.com');
```

Output:

```
test@test-test.com        => valid
test.test@test-test.com   => valid
@test-test.com            => not valid
test@test-test.com.se     => not valid
test@anothertest-test.com => not valid
test@testtest.com         => not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?php

    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
          echo 'Invalid Email';
          die;
    }
    $allowedEmail = array(
                        'gmail.com',
                        'yahoo.com',
                        'stack.com',
                    ); // ALLOWED EMAIL DOMAINS SHOULD BE ADDED INTO THIS ARRAY.

    $emailArr = explode('@', $email);

    if(in_array($emailArr[1], $allowedEmail)) {
        echo 'allowed Email';
    } else {
        echo 'Not allowed Email';
    } 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - will check for correct characters in email and if contains well formed e-mail address:

```
$error = 0;
if($_POST['email']){
    if (!ereg('^[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+'.'@'.'[-!#$%&\'*+\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\.'.
             '[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+$', $_POST['email'])){
                // your mail is incorrect.
                $error++;
    }
}

if($error == 0)
{
   // you have no errors, manipulate entered data
}
```

Comment: as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php    'This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.'

Comment: additional to what @Arun said, this doesn't answer the question (and looks like a copied piece of code that got handed down from the days of long gone ;)

Comment: Arun, I'm working on 5.3.8 and it is working very well. Security varies on server configuration, not only on PHP. If you set your server correct, it will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this

```
 $email = 'myname@sample.com';
 $regex = '/^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@test\-test\.com$/';

 if(preg_match($regex, $email))
 {
    echo 'Valid';
 }
 else
 {
    echo 'Invalid';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers! This worked for me:

```html
$check = "/^[_a-z0-9-.]*@test-test.comt$/i";
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  
  if (!preg_match ($check, $email))
  {
    $error_msg .= '<h4 class="sans-serif">Invalid Email adress!</h4>';
  }
```

Comment: There are some issues with this solution. First, the `$check` regular expression ends with `comt` while it should be `com`, but I guess that's just a typo. Secondly, the dot in `$check` will match *any* character, so it will indeed match `test@test-test.com` but also `test@test-testXcom`. See my answer for an example of using [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this piece of code:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //valid
}
```

PHP version: 5 >= 5.2.0

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php